# I cant transfer html data with form above 3 pages

Tags: php, html, forms, nicedit

[image][image][image]I have 3 pages.

1. a1.php : add record
2. a2.php : do sth
3. a3.php : record them database

But problem is occured, transfering "html data" from a2.php to a3.php.

EXAMPLE:  a record which I try to record to a1.php is that :

```
<form name="form1" type="post" action="sayfa_1.php">
<input type='submit' value=' gidiyoruz' >
<input type='submit' value=' gidiyoruz' >
</form>
```

a1.php --> a2.php --> a3. php

On a2.php, there i no problem. But then. On a3.php when I show coming data, I SEE TWO BUTTON, NO HTML CODES which is above.

pages is below.

thanks.

### a1.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
//]]>
</script>

<form name="form1" type="post" action="a2.php">  

<textarea rows="20" cols="90" id="anlam"  name="anlam"     style="overflow:auto;" >    </textarea>  

<input type="submit" /> 
</form>
```

### a2.php

```
<?php
$anlam=$_GET["anlam"];
echo $anlam;
?>



<?php echo "<form name='fm' id='fm' action='a3.php' method='get'>";  ?>

<textarea rows="2" cols="50" name="anlam" style="visibility:hidden;"  /> <?php echo $anlam; ?> </textarea>

<input type="submit" /> 
</form>
```

### a3.php

```
<?php
$anlam=$_GET["anlam"];



echo nl2br($anlam);
```

Pace images are above. error: a3.php (instead code, there are two button)

Comment: Do you want to print the html as string on the last page? If so, you can use htmlspecialchars()

Answer (score 1):

so you want the page to send your data from one to another when you click submit button!! 
Use if condition with isset.

```
 if(isset($_POST['name_of_submit_button']))
 {
   // your code of next page
 }
```

n similarly continue with another page by giving another name to you submit button and applying the same condition!!

Comment: plus with this function you can combine all three pages in a single page !!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
method="post"
```

for your form. You could also just use an

```
<input type="hidden" name="anlam" value="<?php echo $anlam; ?>"/>
```

to transport your variable content to the last page. Are you sure, that the hidden textarea/input contains the correct value? Check the source code in your browser for this step.

Comment: I tried method=post and <input type="hidden" name="anlam" value="<?php echo $anlam; ?>"/> ... none of succes